# Finding Laurent series of a function by changing variable

Tags: complex-analysis, taylor-expansion, laurent-series

I'm trying to find Laurent series of the following function at $$\mid z\mid<1$$
My function is as follows:
$$f(z)=\dfrac{1}{z(z-1)(z-2)}=\dfrac{1}{z}\left(\dfrac{1}{(z-2)}+\dfrac{1}{(1-z)}\right)$$

My attempt was like this :
$$\dfrac{1}{z}\left(\dfrac{-1}{1+(1-z)}+\sum_{k=0}^{n}z^k\right)=\dfrac{1}{z}\left(\dfrac{-1}{1-\omega}+\sum_{k=0}^{n}z^k\right)$$
 So by calling $$\omega=z-1$$ I made it Taylor series expandable. But I found the wrong answer. Is it because by changing variable I expended my function for point 1 ?

Comment: You are trying to find the LS for $|z|<1$.  Expand around $z=0$.

Comment: and when I substitute omega variable I will find taylor series of that term for point z=1 right? That is where I'm wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINTS:**

Note that for $|z|<1$,

$$\frac{1}{1-z}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty z^n$$

and for $|z|<2<1$

$$\frac{1}{2-z}=\frac12\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(\frac{z}2\right)^n$$